# Qt/C++: Having trouble with writing to XML file using QDom

Tags: xml, qt

For some reason, I cannot write to my XML file. There are no errors as I build my program and the program runs fine. I've added debug statements to my code to make sure the part where I am appending child nodes is being run, and it is. However, it's just not showing up at all in the XML file. Below is the code I have (my code is probably not that good... just started using Qt and C++).

```
    QDomElement root = doc.documentElement();
    QDomNode child = root.firstChild();
    while (child.nodeName() != "RoutineLibrary") {
        child = child.nextSibling();
        if (child.nodeName() == "RoutineLibrary") {
            QDomElement newRoutine = doc.createElement(QString("TEST"));
            QDomText text = doc.createTextNode("abcdef");
            newRoutine.appendChild(text);
            child.appendChild(newRoutine);
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: How do you write back the changes to the file?

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld ---- I have this:
`code`file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
file.write(doc.toByteArray(1));
file.close();

Comment: Check the return values of open() and write().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was. I simply missed a line to write my changes to the QTextStream first, then to the XML file!

(I apologize for the newbie question!)